# How to push instantiated MC into Array dynamically?

Tags: actionscript-3

Im really stuck. I have 5 MC´s that are being spliced from one array at a certain time. In that same function I want to push another movieclips into another array. The two arrays holds mc's that represent right or wrong answers. So when one question is being given a correct answer that questions visualisation alters.
This function holds a incrementing variable as I do want the mc's to be pushed by the user and one at the time. The thing is I cant seem to refer them properly. 
I´ve tried

```
pQuestSum = this[pQuest + pQuestNumber];
```

and

```
pQuestSum = this[pQuest] + pQuestNumber;
```

and pretty much everything I´ve imagined would work...but the problem is I havent tried

the right thing.

when I trace pQuestSum (which would be the reference) I get an error saying thats its not a number.

this is one of 5 mc's named from 1-5:

```
var passedquest1:PassedQuest = new PassedQuest();
```

this is the vars that i try to to build a reference of

```
var pQuest = "passedquest";
var pQuestNumber = 1;
var pQuestSum;
var questCorrArray:Array = [];

if(event.target.hitTestObject(questArray[ix])){
    removeChild(questArray[ix]);
    questArray.splice(ix,1);
    pQuestNumber ++;
    pQuestSum = this[pQuest] + pQuestNumber;
    trace("pQuestSum"); // NaN
    questCorrArray.push(pQuestSum);
    //trace(questArray.length);
    pointsIncreased = false;
        questPoints = 0;
    }
```

How do I refer an existing movieclip when the reference consists of both a string and a number? Hope I made myself somewhat clear:)

Comment: Can you show more code?  And also, it might be good to explain why you're putting movie clips into arrays and what you're doing with said arrays

Comment: What is `pQuest`?  a string?

Comment: Unless you're extending Array, the 'this' will be causing an error. You'll need to refer, instead, to the array variable, ie:  pQuestSum = arrayVariableName[pQuest + pQuestNumber];

Comment: Edited post with code:)

Comment: Are the movieclips already instantiated on the stage?

Comment: yes they are instantiated

Comment: I've got this now :pQuestSum = [pQuest] + [pQuestNumber]; which gives me the correct name and increment but I get a convertion error...."cannot convert passedquest1 to flash.display.DisplayObject

Comment: Sorry - ignore my comment above. I've just realised you can refer to local variables with this["variableName"] syntax. It means you can use a String to specify which local variable you're referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had an instance of an object on your timeline called "passedquest1" (as an example), then you could access it this way:

```
var myObj = this["passedquest" + 1];
```

Or,

```
var pQuest = "passedquest";
var pQuestNumber = 1;
var myObj = this[pQuest+ pQuestNumber.toString()];
```

---

When you do this: `pQuestSum = this[pQuest] + pQuestNumber;`, you are trying add the number to an object (`this[pQuest]`), unless you have number/int var called "passedquest", this will result in NaN.

Comment: So obvious when explained properly...ty very much!