# Accessing a random Object AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, variables, var

I have 9 different movie clips and they are called MC1, MC2, MC3,...,MC9. Then I want to add them randomly. I made a randomizer and it generate numbers from 1 to 9 randomly. And now how can I add them using the random number that I generate. Example:

`var box11:MC[the random number] = new MC[the random number]`, where in the place of [the random number] will stay that number, for ex: var box11:MC2 = new MC2.

And would it be also possible to do the same with box value? For example box[i][j] for different values od i and j will become box11, box32...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flash.utils.getDefinitionByName()` for this.

Example:

```
var theClass:Class = getDefinitionByName("MC" + randNum) as Class;
var instance = new theClass();
```

---

For dynamic istances (the box), see my answer to this question:

[How to push instantiated MC into Array dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16907127/how-to-push-instantiated-mc-into-array-dynamically/16923156#16923156)

Comment: Can I use it with box? For ex: getDefinitionByName("box" + i + j)?